# How do I edit version of an exe file?

Tags: visual-studio, hex, version, exe, resource-editor

Well, I am using Hex Editor (HxD), But I cant seem to find where or what to change for the version, what I know is it is version 92 and I need to change it to 93, How can I change that ?, If there is another way please tell me, I tried visual studio and Resource editor both couldn't even open the exe file.

Thank You.

Comment: http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker

Comment: Thanks but it as well didn't open, if it helps this is the file I'm trying to edit

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qi0nre17zbkbrze/LoginServer.exe?dl=0